# Regex for values between -10 and 10 up to 1 decimal place

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a c# web application that has a control in that I would like to add a regular expression to, but as I'm useless with regular expressions I was hoping someone would be able to help me!

I would like a regex that will accept all values between -10 and 10 and allow up to 1 optional decimal place.

**Successful Inputs**

```
1
-2.1
3.7
-4
5.8
10
-10
```

**Unsuccessful Inputs**

```
10.1
-10.1
3.14159265359
-3.14159265359 and so on
```

I already have a somewhat similar regex in my application `^(0(\.\d{1,4})?|1(\.0{1,4})?)$`. This only accepts positive and negative values to 4dp, I've had a go at changing it (see below) but I'm unsure of how to include the -10 to 10 range.

```
^(0(\.\d{1,1})?|1(\.0{1,1})?)$
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^-?(?:10(?:\.0)?|[0-9](?:\.[0-9])?)$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e-%3f%2810%28%3f%3a%5c.0%29%3f%7c%5b0-9%5d%28%3f%3a%5c.%5b0-9%5d%29%3f%29%5cr%3f%24&i=1%0d%0a-2.1%0d%0a3.7%0d%0a-4%0d%0a5.8%0d%0a10%0d%0a-10%0d%0a%0d%0a10.1%0d%0a-10.1%0d%0a3.14159265359%0d%0a-3.14159265359&o=m)

If you do not want to match `10` with `0` in the fractional part, remove `(?:\.0)?`.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `-?` - 1 or 0 `-` symbols
- `(?:10(?:\.0)?|[0-9](?:\.[0-9])?)` - 2 alternatives:

  - `10(?:\.0)?` - `10` optionally followed with `.0`
  - `|` - or
  - `[0-9](?:\.[0-9])?` - any 1 digit from `0` to `9` followed with an optional sequence of `.` and any 1 digit
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Nice spot on allowing `10.0` - I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @Ian, your regex was actually the same, just capturing groups made the regex engine store each submatch in a memory buffer. For our modern computers, the overhead is insignificant, but it is best practice to keep the resulting match object as clean as it can. Well, at least I believe in that.